# Getting the number from a string (15m)

Tags: java

Okay so what I am trying to do is, in this game called Minecraft, if they type 15h, it would mean 15 hours, or 20m, 20 minutes. So here is what I came up with.

```
String time = args[3];//args[3] is the text they write (15m, 1d, 20h)
            time = time.replace("m", " minutes.");
            time = time.replace("h", " hours.");
            time = time.replace("d", " days.");
            if(time.contains("m"))
            {
                //Convert the minutes into seconds
                                    //In order to do that I have to pull out the number from "15m", so I would have to pull out 15, how would I do that?
            }
```

Comment: OK, it's a good start.  But what if they type "15 minutes"?  Your code will change this to "15 minutes.inutes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `java.util.Scanner` class.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(args[3]);
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    int amount = s.nextInt();
    String unit = s.next();
    if ("m".equals(unit)) {
        // handle minutes
    } else if ("h".equals(unit)) {
        // handle hours
    } else if ("d".equals(unit)) {
        // handle days
    } else {
        // handle unexpected input
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regex to extract the numerical value.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(time);

if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```